# resize jquery function

Tags: jquery, resize

I need to call this function again when the window resizes.

```
 $('#container').height(function(){
   return $(window).height() * 0.6;
});
```

Whats the best way?

Thanks

Comment: `window.onresize` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#container').height(function(){
    return $(window).height() * 0.6;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it reusable I'd do this:

```
       function refresh(){
            $('#container').height(function(){
            return $(window).height() * 0.6;
            });
        });

       $(window).resize(refresh);
       refresh();
```